# SVG: Update through jQuery works in FF, but not in Safari, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, svg

I want to update an embedded SVG. I select the SVG element by using a **jQuery css selector** and alter it's attribute through **jQuery's .attr()** function. It works as expected in FF but shows no effect in Safari. Any Ideas?

**SVG inside my HTML:**

```
  <svg id="svgelem" height="150" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
    <path id = "s3" d = "M 60 70 L 220 30 L 300 60 L 180 120 L 60 70" fill = "green" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "3"/>
   </defs>
   <g fill = "navy">
    <text font-size = "20">
     <textPath xlink:href = "#s3">
       Foo Bar
     </textPath>
    </text>
   </g>
  </svg>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("textPath").text("other text");
$("path").attr("d","M 60 70 L 90 30 L 300 60 L 180 120 L 60 70");
```

**Working Example:**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snies/FmhqX/16/)

- OS: Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Firefox: 11.0
- Safari: 5.1.5 (7534.55.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I got at first i added a id to textpath node like this

```
 <textPath id="test" xlink:href = "#s3">
```

Second i change the way property from text to append because your append html content inside the node and removing first the content inside take a look

```
$("#bt_text").click(function(){
    $("#test").empty().append("other text allalaksddkfdsbbklas sldnsdd");});
$("#bt_coord").click(function(){
    $("path").attr("d","M 60 70 L 90 30 L 300 60 L 180 120 L 60 70");});​
```

Here's the live example

http://jsfiddle.net/FmhqX/23/

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Using the ID and the .empty() function triggers the redraw. I have modified your example a bit http://jsfiddle.net/FmhqX/26/. Notice how the alert() prints the content of attribute "d" of the "path" element. It changes but no redraw is triggered. But if you press the "change Text" button afterwards, the redraw incorporates the change. Is there a way to explicitly trigger the redraw?

Comment: Why doesn't work i really don't know because I check the jquery and already modifying  the attribute `d` with the new values, so i think that the problem it's related to the path element that I assume that's html5 component and dont know whats the behavior

Comment: well i settle for this workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/snies/FmhqX/30/ I will just empty() and append() the current text to trigger the redraw. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not elegant,but working solution. This updates the full svg:

```
$("#svg_cont").html($("#svg_cont").html());
```

where `#svg_cont` is a container div of svg element.

Answer (score 1):

This SVG refresh issue is a difficult issue.  After much research I found the best solution here: http://jcubic.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/working-with-svg-in-jquery/

Basically, create...

```
$.fn.xml = function() {
    return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this[0]);
};

$.fn.DOMRefresh = function() {
    return $($(this.xml()).replaceAll(this));
};
```

then call it with

```
$("#diagram").DOMRefresh(); //where your <svg> tag has id="diagram"
```

It is a miracle, but it works!  (Chrome and Firefox.  I don't know about those other browsers.)

Comment: A quote from the link given: " I found that when I use function document.createElementNS instead of document.createElement elements added to inline SVG using for instance appendChild function everything work fine. "